# Auto-increment of text and numbers up to 1000 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to fill automatically by using 2-3 rows up to 1000.

To be specific - i have 2 separate columns one is common text with few numbers, and second one will increment for each cell.
Like i have the following text with numbers in all cells from row 1 to 1000 rows,
"A21L02341"
In second column i have the following 2 to 3 text with numbers like the below
"0RS"
"0RT"
"0RU"

So the next row should fill with "0RV", then the next "0RW".

any solution...

Comment: Use a loop in vba counting with base 26 and a vlookup converting number to letter?

Answer (score 0):

[Plz check the image attached for clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AraGe.jpg)It's very unclear what you mean, but this is what I understand from it:

`=IF(SEQUENCE(1000,6)=INDEX(SEQUENCE(1000,6),,1),"A21L02341","0R"&CHAR(81+MOD(SEQUENCE(1000,6)-1,6)+1))`

This will create a spill range (Office365 required) of 1000* `A21L023` in column `A`. In each next column it'll generate text `0R` and a character that starts counting at `S`. Where `6` is the number of columns (you can change that to your needs and it'll update dynamically)

[image]

`LET` may come in handy to easily update the column number:
`=LET(col,6,seq,SEQUENCE(1000,col),IF(seq=INDEX(seq,,1),"A21L02341","0R"&CHAR(81+MOD(seq-1,col)+1)))`

Comment: Why QRS, QRT across columns, didn't the OP want down the rows?

Comment: It was very unclear what was expected: `In second column i have the following 2 to 3 text with numbers like the below "0RS" "0RT" "0RU"` maybe he meant row instead of column?